# Shopware 6 meta.html.twig Storefront Template Can't Be Extended

Tags: twig, shopware6, storefront

I am trying to extend the `meta.html.twig` template of the storefront in my own custom theme but it does not work. I successfully extended the `logo.html.twig` template but the `meta.html.twig` template refuses to be extended. How do I resolve the problem.

My directory is `custom/plugins/TheShoeSeller/src/Resources/views/storefront/layout/meta.html.twig`

```html
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/layout/meta.html.twig' %}

    {% block layout_head_meta_tags_charset %}
                
    {% endblock %}

    {% block layout_head_meta_tags_general %}

    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is you plugin active? Are there other plugins which extend the same template?

Comment: Did you clear your cache

Comment: @Alex yes it is active.

Comment: @DarkBee I cleared the cache and it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a cache issue.

If you have access to cli, please try the following commands:

```
bin/console cache:clear

bin/console theme:compile
```

After this, it should work. I did test it with your file in a custom theme.

If not, check if you are using a plugin which is in the way!